# does a php 7.3 cassandra driver exist?

Tags: php, cassandra

I have php 7.3 on Debian 10. I'm trying to get the Apache Cassandra driver for php 7.3.

The one provided by datastax (https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) only works up to 7.1, and the pecl one (pecl install cassandra) also only work up to PHP 7.1.x. Does one for 7.3 exist? I have searched around and can't find it.

Comment: I am searching the same since half a year, but no luck, I also tried to compile Driver for PHP 7.3, but no luck, Because PHP 7.5 VC version is 15, while Datastax manual compilation supports upto 14 or below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP & Ruby drivers are put on hold - they will receive only critical bug fixes but not the new functionality. You should be able to compile existing code for PHP versions beyond 7.1, but DataStax doesn't provide pre-built versions.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if anyone else might provide the 7.3 driver?

Comment: I don’t know... why not built yourself?

Comment: I would love to do that. Are there instructions somewhere for how to do it?

Comment: Just follow official instructions: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/blob/master/ext/README.md

Comment: Hi, DataStax will provide an update shortly for the PHP driver and it will be again compatible with PHP > 7.1. Shortly here means: a few weeks from now.